# How to register a post type and taxonomy in WordPress and display in a page/single post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a question about WordPress register post type:

How can I register a post type like `portfolio`?

For example:
In the WordPress dashboard, I can register a post type and taxonomy. After this I want to create a page to display all the portfolio and taxonomies like (portfolio.php) and display a single portfolio in a (single-portfolio.php).

Can someone explain this for me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447366/creating-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress-with-custom-taxonomy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various methods :

- **Create in your theme a archive-#postypename#.php** (best one)
- Create a page with a custom template name and put there all your code.

For the single page you can, as you write, create a single-#postypename#.php in your theme.

Here's an helpful link:
[How to Create a Custom Post Types Archive Page in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/)

Comment: how can i display may post in a page and single i need a example

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: i created a post type (portfolio) and register taxonomy and display in a page in a (portfolio.php) and display a singlepost in a (single-portfolio.php) you can explain this for me or you can creat a example for me

Comment: Do you need an example of php code about printing the loop of all the portfolios post?

Comment: yes all code to display a texonomy and post